# parse UTF-16 encoded string as xml

Tags: php, xml, utf-16

I have a `UTF-16` encoded xmlstring that I want to parse with php.
encoding to `UTF-8` isn't possible because not all the content can be represented in `UTF-8`

The problem is that when I try to use the `xml_parser_create("UTF-16")` and `xml_parse_into_struct` functions I get a message about UTF-16 not being supported.

What are my options?

Comment: Everything that can be represented in UTF-16 can be represented in UTF-8, and vice-versa.

Comment: At least part of your question is nonsense. If you truly have a UTF-16 encoded string, then you can *always* convert it to UTF-8 encoding. All UTF encodings are capable of representing the entire range of Unicode codepoints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a UTF16 decode function that someone wrote and posted to the php.net, might do the trick, although not guaranteeing it.

http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php#49185

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your UTF-16 string of XML to UTF-8 like this:

```
mb_convert_encoding($yourstring, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-16')
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php

You can take the output of that function and use it with all of your usual functions for XML and what not.  UTF-16  and UTF-8 support the same characters... they just encode it differently.

Answer (score 0):

To convert your UTF-16 string of XML to UTF-8 use below code:

mb_convert_encoding($yourString, ''UTF-16', 'UTF-8');